# Split certain parts of string with different divider signs

Tags: java, regex, string, split

So for instance if I have:

```
String test = "test DE;IT;ES;CH;AU;FR";
```

With `String[] split = test.split("\\W");` I could split the string and put the individual parts of the string into an array.

However what I want is that for instance if I have the same String:

```
String test2 = "test DE; IT;ES ;CH;AU;FR";
```

but this time there are random spaces in between. I want to keep those spaces. The issue is if I only use `;` as a regex the first word would be `test DE` instead of `test` being an own string and `DE` being an own String.

So my desired result for an array would be in this case: `[test,DE, IT,ES ,CH,AU,FR]` (I removed the standard spaces after the comma to make it more clear)

Comment: What would you describe as 'random spaces'? Leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: both leading and trailing spaces should be kept

Comment: So what about [`;|\b +\b`](https://regex101.com/r/cyGApc/1). Would that work in Java? Split on both the semi-colon **or** the space character if it's between multiple words?

Comment: BTW should `AU` not be `AT` for Austria?

Comment: had posted the same answer. deleted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
;|\b +\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ehVJRw/1)

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String test = "test DE; IT;ES ;CH;AU;FR";
      String[] split = test.split(";|\\b +\\b");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[test, DE,  IT, ES , CH, AU, FR]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of lookarounds:

```regex
;|(?<!;) +(?!;)
```

https://regex101.com/r/e0ZtAa/1